# C# OracleCommand SQL Call Procedure with Params

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, parameters

I would like to call a (Oracle) Procedure from C#. My Code:

```
try
{
    OracleConnection myOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    myOracleConnection.Open();
    OracleCommand command = myOracleConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = String.Format("BEGIN MISSINGTABLES ('{0}', '{1}'); END;", "PEKA_ERP_001", "ASE_ERP_001");
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myOracleConnection.Close();
}
catch (OracleException e)
{
    throw e;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

The Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES (S1 IN VARCHAR2, S2 IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN [...]
```

on `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` I get an Exception..:

```
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
OracleException Unhandled
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you concatenating a string an not using [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.aspx)?

Comment: Because I don't really know, how I use the Parameters. You can see, that I need them between the -> BEGIN ... END Statement. How to do then the Placeholders ..?

Comment: There are _many_ tutorials on the web, did you even search before asking?

Comment: sry guys, next time, I will search ;) Did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it :)

```
OracleCommand command = myOracleConnection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "MISSINGTABLES";
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("S1", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = "PEKA_ERP_001";
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("S2", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = "ASE_ERP_001";
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
myOracleConnection.Close();
```